# Item status relation database design

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database

The items in question could be anything, in my case they are files uploaded by the user.

I have the following table:

```
Files table -  file_id (pk), user_id (fk), file_name
```

How can I store a banned status about each file?

I thought about having a banned_files table, but then users can also delete files, disable files and files can be pending. That would mean a table for every status, which doesn't sound like a good idea.

#### Update #1

A file should be able to have more than one status, for example a file could be banned and also be deleted. So if the user un-deletes their file, it will still be banned.

#### Update #2

When a file is banned, a reason for the ban needs to be recorded. I have my reasons in the following table:

```
Reasons table -  reason_id (pk), reason_text
```

Comment: What about `status` column in same table? It seems simple, it isn't?

Comment: The issue with that solution is that a file can't be deleted and banned at the same time. I've update the question with that requirement.

Comment: In that case you add 2 columns `is_deleted` and `is_banned`.

Comment: but then I will also require is_pending, is_disabled and then any other status' that my users require. Doesn't seem like great design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
files
    id              unsigned int(P)
    user_id         unsigned int(F users.id)
    path            varchar(200)

files_statuses
    id              unsigned int(P)
    status_id       unsigned int(F statuses.id)
    reason_id       unsigned int(F reasons.id) ALLOW NULL, DEFAULT NULL

reasons
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(100) // Offensive material, etc.

statuses
    id              unsigned int(P)
    description     varchar(50) // Banned, Deleted, etc.
```

Comment: Would you favour this approach over separate tables for banned files, deleted files, pending files etc? If I want to store more information about files that are being uploaded or files that have been deleted, would separate tables then be a better decision?

Comment: @paul - yes, I would probably favour this approach rather than separate tables for deleted/banned/etc files.

Comment: But if I want to store which user banned the file, what time it was banned etc, how would they fit into this approach?

Comment: If you have a lot of information that applies to a particular status (like banned) then you might indeed create another table that contains information specific to that file and that status. But your `files` table will contain all the information that is common among files regardless of their status: filename, user_id, etc. You might also consider having a `status_history` table that tracks all the status changes to a file that would contain a datetime stamp, user_id and whatever else you wanted to track.

Answer (score 2):

Create a table of possible statuses, and an intersection table between that and the Files table. A file has a particular status if it is joined through the intersection table to it.

Comment: Yes this is one idea I had, but for the banned status, i'd like to store a reason for the ban. My ban reasons are in a separate table. Could this solution accommodate reasons for the ban?

Comment: You'd just include a reference to the ban reason in the join table, or have multiple ban statuses that each have their own reason. Either method would extend to allowing reasons for any of the statuses.

Comment: would it be possible for you to update your answer with some more detail? So for the first option, in my intersection table I'd have the file_id, status_id and then an extra column that I'd keep a reference to a ban reason, and it would be null for status' that don't require a reason?