# Separate tables or pivot table (or both)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Users of my site can upload **files**. I have come up with two designs for modelling a **file status**, with help from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844815/item-status-relation-database-design).

Example statuses are - *deleted, pending, banned, uploading*

### Design A - Separate Tables

*files* - file_id(pk) | user_id(fk) | file_name

*banned files* - file_id(fk) | ban_reason | admin_user | time

*deleted files* - file_id(fk) | perm_delete | time | deleted_by

*pending files* - file_id(fk) | start_time | waiting_for

---

### Design B - Pivot Table & Separate info table (both)

*files* - file_id(pk) | user_id(fk) | file_name

*statuses* - status_id(pk) status_text

*file statuses* - file_id(fk) | status_id(fk) | info_id(fk) <-- **this links to a record in another table that stores info about this status e.g (ban_reason, admin_user, time)**

*banning info* - info_id(fk) | ban_reason | admin_user | time

*deleted info* - info_id(fk) | perm_delete | time | deleted_by

*pending info* - info_id(fk) | start_time | waiting_for

---

*My main concern with design A is that when selecting a file, I would have to join on several tables to check if they are banned etc. Design B is intended to prevent the need to perform joins as I would only need to join with one table.*

**Which design would you recommend?**

**Would select queries be too slow with design A?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about performance, you could include a BIT column in the files table called active.  A 1 means it is active, 0 it is not.  This would let you find all active files with only a single table, but you would have some overhead maintaining it.  This would go well with design A.

Comment: Thanks, I considered that, but doesn't seem like a great idea as it's certain the active field will get out of sync.

Is a select from files where the file_id isn't in 4 or 5 other tables a cause for concern then?

Comment: Will you only select one file at a time?  It depends on how heavy your load is.  If you index the file id of the other tables and only do a seek on one file id, it won't be too bad.  It is really load dependendant based on how large your tables get.

Comment: More often that not it would be one file at a time.

Comment: That helps speed it up.  Design B would work better if you just need to see if a file is banned/deleted/pending since it would only be a single index seek.